# SpringBoot IntelliJ: distinguish my own logs versus framework based logs

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, logging

Small question regarding SpringBoot, IntelliJ and Grep Console please.

I am going to use a very small example code:

```
    @GetMapping("/api/employees/{id}")
    Mono<Employee> one(@PathVariable String id) {
                logger.info("<===== {IMPORTANT} please highlight this line!!!");

        return Mono.just(DB.stream().filter(employee -> employee.id().equals(id)).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Couldn't find " + id)));
    }
```

Please note the logger line is at info level. I do not want to introduce custom levels please.

When launching the application and performing queries, even at INFO level, we see many logs related to SpringBoot framework:

Like for instance:
`2023-01-31T05:57:19.644+08:00  INFO [Tutorial,,] 24404 --- [           main] s.b.s.SpringBootLoggingApplication       : Started SpringBootLoggingApplication in 4.104 seconds (process running for 4.812)`

I paste one here, but usually, it is a lot.

And in the middle of those, there would be some real application log, some custom log developers from the project would write.

I do not want to "silence" the SpringBoot logs, they are very useful, but rather, just "highlight" the application logs, without creating a different log level just for my logs in development.

For instance, in IntelliJ, ERROR messages are highlight in orange, WARN messages are highlighted in yellow, etc..

Is it possible to highlight my custom messages with my own color?

What I have tried:
I am using Grep Console plugin in IntelliJ. Here is the configuration (please see screenshot)

[image]

However, the log line is not being highlighted.

What am I missing please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can grep, filter, and highlight the log contents with specific words by enabling the [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Ethan. I tried Grep Console plugin, added my keyword, but still no highlight. Could you please share a configuration?